# Refactoring a method with too many bool in it

Tags: c#, methods, refactoring

I have this method in c#, and I wish to refactor it. There are just too many bools and lines. What would be the best refactoring. Making a new class seems a bit overkill, and cutting simply in two seems hard. Any insight or pointer would be appreciated.

method to refactor

```cs
    private DialogResult CheckForSireRestrictionInSubGroup(bool deletingGroup,string currentId)
    {
        DialogResult result = DialogResult.No;
        if (!searchAllSireList)
        {
            DataAccessDialog dlg = BeginWaitMessage();
            bool isClose = false;
            try
            {
                ArrayList deletedSire = new ArrayList();
                ISireGroupBE sireGroupBE = sireController.FindSireGroupSearch();

                if (sireGroupBE != null)
                {
                    //if the current group is in fact the seach group before saving
                    bool currentGroupIsSeachGroup = sireGroupBE.TheSireGroup.id == currentId; 

                    //if we have setting this group as search group
                    bool selectedAsSearchGroup = this.chkBoxSelectedSireGroup.Checked;

                    //if the group we currently are in is not longer the seach group(chk box was unchecked)
                    bool wasSearchGroup = currentGroupIsSeachGroup && !selectedAsSearchGroup;

                    //if the group is becoming the search group
                    bool becomesSearchGroup = !currentGroupIsSeachGroup && selectedAsSearchGroup;

                    //if the group being deleted is in fact the search group
                    bool deletingSearchGroup = deletingGroup && currentGroupIsSeachGroup;

                    //if the user checked the checkbox but he's deleting it, not a so common case, but
                    //we shouldn't even consider to delete sire in this case
                    bool deletingTemporarySearchGroup = deletingGroup && !currentGroupIsSeachGroup;         

                    //if we are not deleting a temporary search group and it's either
                    //becoming one (without deleting it) or we already are the search group
                    bool canDeleteSires = !deletingTemporarySearchGroup && 
                                          (becomesSearchGroup || currentGroupIsSeachGroup);
                    //we only delete sires if we are in search group
                    if (canDeleteSires)
                    {   
                        if (deletingSearchGroup || wasSearchGroup)
                        {
                            // If we deleted all sires
                            deletedSire = new ArrayList();
                            deletedSire.AddRange( sireGroupBE.SireList);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //if we delete a few sire from the change of search group
                            deletedSire = GetDeleteSire(sireGroupBE.SireList);
                        }
                    }

                    EndWaitMessage(dlg);
                    isClose = true;
                    result =  ShowSubGroupAffected(deletedSire);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!isClose)
                {
                    EndWaitMessage(dlg);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest way of expressing the logic - it is easy to read, and is also well commented. I would not touch it at all.

Comment: Agreed .... it may be lengthy but it's readable.

Comment: I'm of the opinion the current code is readable, but detracts from the goal of the method, to delete entries. The boolean logic can remain as it is and migrate to another method such that the main method can cut down on the "support" code that doesn't address the main issue of deleting stuff.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth True, I will cut down the support code to maintain the 1 'goal' per method. But it seems most people think this is readable and this was my main concern, since I'm doing legacy code and I want the next guy to understand why I did this.

Comment: @Xavier I don't think you can go wrong either way, at this point it seems to me to be more personal taste than good practice. If you are happy with the current code, then by all means leave it - it is perfectly readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to refactor out each of the primary booleans (`canDeleteSires`, `deletingSearchGroup || wasSearchGroup`) into methods with names that describe the readable version of the logic:

```
if (WeAreInSearchGroup())
{
    if (WeAreDeletingAllSires())
    {
        deletedSire = new ArrayList();
        deletedSire.AddRange( sireGroupBE.SireList);
    }
    else
    {
        deletedSire = GetDeleteSire(sireGroupBE.SireList);
    }
}
```

You then encapsulate your current boolean logic inside these methods, how you pass state (method arguments or class members) is a matter of taste.

This will remove the booleans from the main method into smaller methods that ask and answer a question directly. I've seen this approach used in the "comments are evil" style of development. To be honest, I find this a little overkill if you are a lone-wolf, but in a team it can be much easier to read.

Out of personal preference I would also invert your first if statement to return early, this will reduce the indentation level of the entire method:

```
if (searchAllSireList)
{
    return result;
}

DataAccessDialog dlg = BeginWaitMessage();
bool isClose = false;
try
...
```

But then you might get chastised by the "multiple returns are evil" crowd. I get the impression development practice is like politics...

Comment: +1 for the early-return approach.  Too many developers fear this, but it is a great way to improve the clarity of a block like this.  And simple.

Comment: @CarlManaster I agree with you here, I tend to favour early returns if there are bomb-out clauses. I tend to favour single returns if there are multiple possible return values that are relevant to the logic, if that makes any sense lol

Comment: Oh, the team I work with are in the sect of the one return per method. So not much of choice here. Personnaly I'm not fixed yet if this practice is evil or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small refactor for removing some indentation:

```
private DialogResult CheckForSireRestrictionInSubGroup(bool deletingGroup,string currentId)
{
    if (searchAllSireList)
        return DialogResult.No;

    DataAccessDialog dlg = BeginWaitMessage();
    bool isClose = false;

    try
    {
        ISireGroupBE sireGroupBE = sireController.FindSireGroupSearch();

        if (sireGroupBE == null)
            return DialogResult.No;

        //if the current group is in fact the seach group before saving
        bool currentGroupIsSeachGroup = sireGroupBE.TheSireGroup.id == currentId; 

        //if we have setting this group as search group
        bool selectedAsSearchGroup = this.chkBoxSelectedSireGroup.Checked;

        //if the group we currently are in is not longer the seach group(chk box was unchecked)
        bool wasSearchGroup = currentGroupIsSeachGroup && !selectedAsSearchGroup;

        //if the group is becoming the search group
        bool becomesSearchGroup = !currentGroupIsSeachGroup && selectedAsSearchGroup;

        //if the group being deleted is in fact the search group
        bool deletingSearchGroup = deletingGroup && currentGroupIsSeachGroup;

        //if the user checked the checkbox but he's deleting it, not a so common case, but
        //we shouldn't even consider to delete sire in this case
        bool deletingTemporarySearchGroup = deletingGroup && !currentGroupIsSeachGroup;         

        //if we are not deleting a temporary search group and it's either
        //becoming one (without deleting it) or we already are the search group
        bool canDeleteSires = !deletingTemporarySearchGroup && 
                              (becomesSearchGroup || currentGroupIsSeachGroup);

        ArrayList deletedSire = new ArrayList();

        //we only delete sires if we are in search group
        if (canDeleteSires)
        {   
            if (deletingSearchGroup || wasSearchGroup)
            {
                // If we deleted all sires
                deletedSire.AddRange(sireGroupBE.SireList);
            }
            else
            {
                //if we delete a few sire from the change of search group
                deletedSire = GetDeleteSire(sireGroupBE.SireList);
            }
        }

        EndWaitMessage(dlg);
        isClose = true;
        return ShowSubGroupAffected(deletedSire);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!isClose)
        {
            EndWaitMessage(dlg);
        }
    }
    return DialogResult.No;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I personally would leave it as it is. The booleans that you have all over the place, although inefficient, make this function readable and easy to understand.

You could do something like combine all the bools onto a single line (like below), however that is not as maintainable as what you wrote.

x = ((a & b) & ! d) | e;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try removing all the comments. The bool variables you have are adding value to the code understanding, you could put several of them inline for canDeleteSires, but I don't think that will add any value.

By the other hand, that code is in your form, so it may be better in your controller so you can keep the form simple and the controller actually controlling the behavior.

Comment: Hehe, you spoted something I also spoted. It's indeed not at the good place. It's old code I'm refactoring for readability. I'll probly put it in some controller next or anywhere not in the view.

Comment: But that will give you readability. I think the code is good in the way it is now, I think it's ready for the "next level".